# php string replace quotes

Tags: php, str-replace

Hello I am trying to get all single quotes to be double quotes using the php str_replace however it does not seem to be working no matter what I do, suggestions

```
$page = str_replace("/'/", '/"/', $page);
```

Comment: You do not need to escape the characters as they are inside the other quote type

Comment: You're thinking regex.  You don't need `/ /` for string replace.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Update: I'd agree with others that the following is an easier-to-read alternative for most folks:

```
$page = str_replace("'", '"', $page);
```

My original answer:

```
$page = str_replace(chr(39), chr(34), $page);
```

Comment: This one worked thanks guys, waiting for the ten minutes to click it as accepted answer.

Comment: You should remove *magic numbers* from your code where possible.

Comment: I don't think you mean those *[magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))*?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to escape the quote character (in fact it is `\`, not `/`, unless you were confused with the standard regex delimiters) if the string isn't delimited with the same character.

```
$page = str_replace("'", '"', $page);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
str_replace("'",'"',$text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$page = str_replace("'", "\"", $page);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do replacements with [preg_replace();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$str = "'Here 'it' goes'";
echo preg_replace("/'/", '"', $str);
```

Comment: However, PHP manual says that you should use str_replace() for that, so Patrick's answer should work well.

Answer (score 0):

This works. You actually don't need any escaping character.

```
$page = str_replace("'", '"', $page);
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need the start and end `/` for `preg_...()` (and other regex) functions. For basic functions such as `str_replace`, simply use the characters:

```
str_replace("'", '"', $text);
```